# Is there a way to simplify getting the character that appears the most in a collection with Linq?

Tags: c#, strings, linq, collections

I have a collection of strings, all of which are three characters in length:

```
string[] test = { "abc", "bbc", "cbc", "aac", "bac", "ccc" };
```

I want to determine which `char` is present as the center character in the most number of elements. I've created a Linq query that accomplishes this goal:

```
var champion = test.GroupBy(g => g[1])
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count())
                   .OrderByDescending(o => o.Value)
                   .First();
Console.WriteLine(champion.Key);
```

In this case, the output should be:

> b

However, I can't help but feel like it could be simplified.

---

Is there a way to simplify my Linq query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a dictionary. Instead, order by the count directly:

```cs
var champion = test.GroupBy(t => t[1])
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                   .First();
```

Note that this might do the count per group several times while sorting. For a very large number of items, you could improve it by storing the result in a [ValueTuple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) before sorting.

```cs
var champion = test.GroupBy(t => t[1])
    .Select(g => (key: g.Key, count: g.Count()))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.count)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine($"The champion '{champion.key}' occurred {champion.count} times.");
```

`Select` does not use an intermediate collection, but produces an `IEnumerable<(char, int)>` on the fly as it is iterated by `OrderByDescending`.

See also: [Deferred Execution of LINQ Query](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution)

Answer (score 2):

The following code part could be inefficient for large sets:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.count)
.First();
```

We don't need sorting at all, we need just to find an item with the maximum value.
Let's create a couple of extension methods for this.
For reference types:

```
private static TSource MaxItem<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    where TSource : class
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    // TODO: validate arguments

    TSource maxItem = null;
    TKey max = default(TKey);
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        TKey value = keySelector(element);
        if (maxItem == null || value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        {
            max = value;
            maxItem = element;
        }
    }

    return maxItem;
}
```

And for value types:

```
private static TSource? MaxValueItem<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    where TSource : struct
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    // TODO: validate arguments

    TSource? maxItem = null;
    TKey max = default(TKey);
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        TKey value = keySelector(element);
        if (maxItem == null || value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        {
            max = value;
            maxItem = element;
        }
    }

    return maxItem;
}
```

As you can see, there is no additional memory allocation unlike the `OrderByDescending` method.

---

Use it:

```
var champion = test.GroupBy(g => g[1])
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count())
                   .MaxValueItem(o => o.Value);
Console.WriteLine(champion.Key);
```

The same for the [@Olivier's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/268059/39186):

```
var champion = test.GroupBy(t => t[1])
    .Select(g => (key: g.Key, count: g.Count()))
    .MaxValueItem(o => o.Value);
```

Comment: ...and if you're on .net-6 there is a new extension for it: `MaxBy`.